# Apache can't access Python's module 'numpy' - linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, apache, tensorflow

I run apache2 on Ubuntu 17.10. Inside a php file there is:

```
<?php
exec("python3 test_python.py 2>&1",$res);
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($res); $i++) {
  echo $res[$i] . '<br>';
}
?>
```

and inside *test_python.py* there is:

```
import numpy as np
print("it works from here.");
```

Unfortunately, the result i get is:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_python.py", line 1, in
import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'*

When i run the script my self through terminal like:

```
python3 test_python.py
```

it works fine. I suspect there's a problem with permissions but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a `PATH`/[`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) issue. The `python3` you are running from your interactive shell might not be the same as the one Apache/PHP runs; and/or the [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) might differ in both cases, so `numpy` is found in one case, but not the other.

The safest and the most robust way for running your Python script with dependencies, is to create a virtual environment with [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), activate it, install your deps there:

```
cd /path/to/project             # go to your project dir
virtualenv -p python3 env       # create python3-based virtual environment
. env/bin/activate              # activate the virtual environment in env/
pip install numpy               # install all dependencies
deactivate                      # deactivate env
```

and then simply run your Python script from PHP by invoking `python` from the virtual environment just created (`env/bin/python`):

```
<?php
exec("/path/to/project/env/bin/python test_python.py 2>&1", $res);
...
```

All packages installed inside the virtual environment will now be available in `test_python.py`.

To add other packages, just activate your virtual env again, and `pip` install there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that this was the problem indeed.